# How to find test cases by name in QC using VBA

Tags: vba, hp-quality-center, alm

So i trying to find test cases by name in QC
I can find test case by nodeID,Path etc. but not by name.
What i am trying to do is Something like QC Menu->Edit->Find (Enter your test case name)
Can this be done using OTA ?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Nothing; QC stands for Quality Center - it's a product of Micro Focus - https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/products/alm-quality-center/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a query using the TD connection object

```
set oCommand=oTDC.Command
oCommand.CommandText="Select * from TEST where TS_NAME Like'testname'"
oRecordSet.Execute
Do until recordset.EOR=true
/Get your test case details
recordset.next
Loop
```